# Automation Anywhere - How to get the number of times a value is shown in an Excel file using counter system variable and store it in a variable?

Tags: variables, counter, automationanywhere

I have the following loop command, which loops through the rows of an Excel file and stores the values into a user-defined variables.

[image]

...What I'm attempting to do is get the number of times the vH1 appears in an Excel file using the system counter variable and then store the count results into a user-defined variable. Could I please get some help on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Excel Find/Replace command. It will retrieve a list, loop through it to count how many times a value appear. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped set me on the right path and I was able to produce the requirements. ...I greatly appreciate the assistance